# MySQL select join order by

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

`tb_user` with these fields:
`userId`, `lastName`, `firstName` and other fields.

`tb_application` with these fields:
`ApplicationID`, `ApplicantID`, `applicationType`, `applicationStatus`, `applicationCycle` and other fields.

Using this statement I get the recordset of the applications ordered by ApplicationID.

```
SELECT tb_application.ApplicationID, tb_application.ApplicantID, 
 tb_application.applicationType, tb_application.applicationCycle, 
 tb_application.applicationStatus 
WHERE applicationCycle = '10' and applicationType ='5' and and applicationStatus ='1' 
ORDER BY tb_application.ApplicationID
```

Then, I use the field `ApplicantID` from the applications table to retrieve the name from the users table.

But what I need to have is the list of applications ordered by Last name.

After receiving the answer from Raphael and thanks to his diligence and introducing me to the power of the "JOIN" instruction in MySQL, I modify his answer and the one that works for me is this:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_application 
    INNER JOIN tb_user ON tb_application.ApplicantID=tb_user.userId 
        WHERE applicationCycle = '10' 
        and applicationType='5' 
    and applicationStatus='1' 
        ORDER BY lastName
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
 --u.lastName, 
  tb_t.ApplicationID, 
  t.ApplicantID, 
  t.applicationType, 
  t.applicationCycle, 
  t.applicationStatus
FROM tb_application t
INNER JOIN tb_user u 
   ON t.ApplicantID = u.userId
WHERE 
 applicationCycle = '10' 
AND
 applicationType ='5' 
AND
 applicationStatus ='1' 
ORDER BY u.lastName
```

Comment: +1 . . . Although I would throw the last name into the `select` as well.  It seems weird to order by something you cannot see.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but world is sometimes so weird ;) Indeed that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, Your answer show me how to use the "INNER JOIN" an how useful it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can comma-sparate multiple fields to sort after, like this

```
ORDER BY tb_application.ApplicationID, tb_user.lastName
```

This means that it will first sort after `tb_application.ApplicationID`, and within that range it will sort after `tb_user.lastName`